# Angular / CSS style change width of row items

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am conceiving a horizontal bar containing items.
They must all be of same width, having the same spacing between them.
They can expand as much as they want vertically (

[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-row-space)

[image: nicely spaced]

**Problem:**
How to automatically set the width of the row elements? Here I simply put a value that looks good: `width:200px`.

I want them to have a width dependent on the number of element per row.

**What I tried:**
Using elementRef in Horizontile (component holding the individual tiles, displaying with *ngFor) to get the width of this element:

```js
currentWidth:number;
constructor(private el:ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.currentWidth=this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth;}
```

it returns 5. (??) Using .width returns nothing. Also this is not recommended, I'd like another solution, less coupling.

I noticed I can make use of `width:inherit;` in the css of the individual tile component, which allows me to set the style from the horizontal list component.

`<app-tile [style.width.px]="0.9*currentWidth/nDisplayedTiles" [tile]="item"></app-tile>`

As the `currentWidth` value is zero, of course it doesn't work;

I tried setting it in % but the `inherits` css tag keeps the %, which is not the intended effect.
Why is the app-tile styling not cared about if `inherits` is not set?
I tried using ViewEncapsulation but it had no effect either.

This looks like a trivial matter though: did I just miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `offsetParent` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent)) width and create a method to return the value on each of the cells and call it in your `[style.width.px]`, something like the following will work.

> The `HTMLElement.offsetParent` read-only property returns a reference to the element which is the closest (nearest in the containment hierarchy) positioned ancestor element.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-row-space-c81so1?file=src/app/horizontile/horizontile.component.ts)

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //added this as the compiler was throwing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.currentWidth=this.el.nativeElement.offsetParent.clientWidth;
    });
  }

  getWidth(): number{
     let width:number = 0;

     //you may need to change this value to better display the cells
     let multiplier = 0.7;

      width = (this.currentWidth * multiplier) / this.ndisplayTiles;

      width = Math.round(width);

      return width;
  }

<app-tile [class]="'layout-tile'" [tile]="item"  [style.width.px]="getWidth()">
</app-tile>
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Could you explain why `offsetParent` was needed? And why `clientWidth` and not `offsetWidth`?